# Managing MySQL hierarchy data

Tags: mysql

I have a below "User_Info". It carries all user info and the ID of the company that each user belongs to.

```
User_Id | User_Name | Company_Id
--------+-----------+--------------
1002    | User1     | 113
1003    | User2     | 114
1004    | User3     | 111
```

I have another table "Company" which has Company Information and its associated Parent Company.

```
id  | Company_Name    | Parent_Company_Id
----+-----------------+------------------
110 | WALMART         | NULL
111 | WALMART TEXAS   | 110
112 | WALMART DALLAS  | 111
113 | WALMART HOUSTON | 111
114 | WALMART KATY    | 113
```

How do I get the below output? The Company_id in the User_Info table should list all the hierarchical companies under that Company_id.

```
user_id  | company_id
---------+--------------
1002     | 113
1002     | 111
1002     | 110
1003     | 114
1003     | 111
1003     | 110
1004     | 111
1004     | 110
```

Comment: Did you even look at this before posting it :(

Comment: Sorry its my first time in posting a question. i wish i could create it in a tabular format. can you help me out with the answer

Comment: First time or hundredth time, you could easily see that this question wasn't ready to post. Please visit the Formatting help pages to find out how to construct your post. Then add capital letters to your English sentences.

Comment: Can you please help me with the answer now. I have edited my question.

Comment: Better. I've improved it more. Don't know the answer, sorry.

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: The resultant dataset that i want is repeating the users till it reaches its parent company. Flattening the hierarchy would bring the results in a single row but i want it to be displayed in seperate rows. The above link doesent show that. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this query (disclaimer follows):

```
select user_id,
       company_id
from   (
        select     u.id as user_id,
                   c.id as company_id,
                   c.parent_company_id,
                   u.company_id as user_company_id
        from       user_info u,
                   company c
        order by   1, 2 desc
        limit      10000000000000000000
       ) base
where  company_id in (user_company_id, @p)
and    if(@p := parent_company_id, 1, 1)
```

#### Disclaimer

MySql is not really suited for doing hierarchical queries, as it does not support the ISO standard *common table expression* nor *recursion* syntax.

But MySql does support the use of variables which can be modified during the execution of SQL statements. This is in general not a reliable way to get results, as MySql is free to change the sequence of evaluation, and order of intermediate results, while executing a query.

But if you are willing to take that risk, the above query leads MySql into a certain sequence, albeit it at a cost: the query performs a Cartesian product between the two tables.

#### Conditions

There is a condition: the company records should all have parent ID values which are not greater than their own ID. So `parent_company_id < id OR parent_company_id IS NULL` must be true for all records. Otherwise the above query will not give complete results.

#### Explanation of the Query

First the Cartesian product is returned by the inner query. The order is important. Here it is assumed that MySql will in fact apply the order, because in theory, MySql is allowed to just ignore this and maybe use an interesting index. One way to increase the likelihood that MySql will apply the `order by` is to set a limit. For low limits, it is clear MySql must apply the order for it to identify the right records. The goal of a very high limit is to force MySql into applying this order, and yet get all records.

The main logic is in the `where` clause. Initially the `@p` variable is `null`, so the first condition will actually become true when the company matches the user's company. When that happens the second "condition" of the `where` clause will also be evaluated. That one really is a fake condition, because it always returns 1, and thus is always true. But in evaluating, the variable `@p` is updated to the parent company ID, which is the only purpose of that "condition".

So now when another record is tested, the company ID can be either the user's company or the parent company ID currently stored in `@p`. Here it is evident that the order of records must be by user ID, and then by company ID, where company parents are ordered after their children. This is why the inner query orders company IDs in descending order.

Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87da0b/1).

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed answer. This really helps!! Thank you again :)

Comment: How do i use this query as a View? Since View does not support variables and nested select queries. I tried creating a VIEW  for the nested select query and a function                                                    create function parent_value() 
returns INT DETERMINISTIC 
NO SQL 
return @p;              I then created another View                                select user_name,
              user_company_id,     
from Test_user_view
where  company_id in (user_company_id, parent_value())
and    if(@p := parent_company_id, 1, 1). The result set is NOT what i want. Pls help

Comment: That is worth another question. These comments are not really suited for follow-up questions. A solution based on a view (and thus: without variables) will need to work quite differently.